# Why can't I iterate through an NSArray?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In Objective-C I always did this:

```
for (SKSpriteNode *sprite in sprites.children) {

   //Do something for every sprite.
}
```

But when I try to do the same thing in swift I get problems.

I do it like this:

```
 for sprite: SKSpriteNode in sprites.children {

   //Do something for every sprite.
  }
```

This gives me the error: 
*Reference to generic method 'children' is ambiguous without more context*

I'm fairly new to swift, I just started learning yesterday, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: error messages with Swift are sometimes strange... have you tried instead `for sprite in sprites.children as SKSpriteNode { ... ` ?

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: How is `sprites` defined?

Comment: Try like this - for obj : AnyObject in sprites.children {
    if let xyz = obj as? SKSpriteNode {
        
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the array. I dont know why apple did like this but this is the way to do it:

```
for sprite in sprites.children as [SKSpriteNode] {
    // If you know for sure that every child is an SKSpritNode
}

// OR

for child in sprites.children {
    if let sprite = child as? SKSpriteNode {
        // To be 100% sure
    }
}
```

Comment: it said i had to ad ! after as in the first for loop

Comment: why? because you cannot iterate over an unknown object.

Comment: You probably have xcode 6.3 with Swift 1.2 (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22). My answer is in 1.1.